# JQuery not working inside modal

Tags: javascript, jquery

### The Scripts Used

**PHP Script**

```
<?php
    $files = glob("../Desktop/IMG/BananzaNews/Thumbs/*.*");
    echo '<div class="SwitchPages"><div class="WrapPages">'; //First tab
    $t = 0;
    for ($i=0; $i<count($files); $i++)
    {
        $root = "http://www.rafflebananza.com/";
        $imagePath = str_replace("../", "",$files[$i]);
        $withoutExt = preg_replace('/\\.[^.\\s]{3,4}$/', '', $imagePath);
        $imageName = str_replace("Desktop/IMG/BananzaNews/Thumbs/", "", $withoutExt);

        if( $i % 8 == 0 ) {
            $t = $t + 1;
            echo '<div id="Page_'.$t.'_Content" class="Pages">'; //hidden class
        }

        echo '<div class="UploadedImgs">
                <div class="ImgName">'.$imageName.'</div>
                <div class="IMG">
                    <img src="'.$root.$imagePath.'" alt="'.$imageName.'" />
                </div>
            </div>';

        if( $i > 0 && $i % 7 == 0 && $i != count($files) - 1 ) {
            echo '</div>';
        }
        if( $i % 7 == 0 && $i == count($files) - 1 ) {
            echo '</div>';
        } else if($i == count($files) - 1 && $i % 7 != 0 ) {
            echo "</div></div>";
        }
    }
    $t = 1;
    echo '<div class="TabSwitcher">';
    for ($i=0; $i<count($files); $i++)
    {
        if( $i % 8 == 0 ) {
            echo '<div class="Tab" id="Page_'.$t.'">'.$t.'</div>';
            $t = $t + 1;
        }
    }
    echo '</div></div>';
?>
```

**On Click Displays...**

```
$('.modal_2').modal_box({
    title:'Second Title Box',
    description:'<?php $a=glob("../Desktop/IMG/BananzaNews/Thumbs/*.*");echo '<div class="SwitchPages"><div class="WrapPages">';$b=0;for($c=0;$c<count($a);$c++){$d="http://www.rafflebananza.com/";$e=str_replace("../","",$a[$c]);$f=preg_replace('/\\.[^.\\s]{3,4}$/','',$e);$g=str_replace("Desktop/IMG/BananzaNews/Thumbs/","",$f);if($c%8==0){$b=$b+1;echo '<div id="Page_'.$b.'_Content" class="Pages">';}echo '<div class="UploadedImgs"><div class="ImgName">'.$g.'</div><div class="IMG"><img src="'.$d.$e.'" alt="'.$g.'" /></div></div>';if($c>0&&$c%7==0&&$c!=count($a)-1){echo '</div>';}if($c%7==0&&$c==count($a)-1){echo '</div>';}else if($c==count($a)-1&&$c%7!=0){echo "</div></div>";}}$b=1;echo '<div class="TabSwitcher">';for($c=0;$c<count($a);$c++){if($c%8==0){echo '<div class="Tab" id="Page_'.$b.'">'.$b.'</div>';$b=$b+1;}}echo '</div></div>';?>'
});
```

**JQuery**

```
var width = 0;  //you original issue, initialize it with a start value
var tabs = $('.TabSwitcher .Tab'); //store it do not look it up over and over
var numOfTabs = tabs.length;

tabs.each( function() {  //use each to loop
    width = width + $(this).width();  //"this" is the current tab
});

width = width + (numOfTabs * 10) // Add padding
$('.TabSwitcher').css({'width': width + 'px'});

$('.Pages .UploadedImgs').click(function(e) {
    url = $(this).children(".IMG").find("img").attr("src");
    $('#file').text(url);
    $("#server_img").val(url);
});

$('.TabSwitcher .Tab:first-child').addClass('Active');
$('.TabSwitcher .Tab').click(function() {
    if (!$(this).hasClass('Active')) {
        show = '#' + $(this).attr('id') + '_Content';
        $('.TabSwitcher .Tab').removeClass('Active');
        $(this).addClass('Active');
        $('.WrapPages .Pages').hide();
        $(show).show();
    }
});
```

### The Problem

Please don't be confused, this is not a PHP question. My PHP creates the content which fully works **IF** it is not in my modal box, however if the script is in my modal, it does not work and by this I mean it does display and whatnot, just the functions to switch tab and whatnot will not work.

Presumably it is because on load my modal is not visible therefore I probably need to know how to do all my JQuery script stuff on something which is hidden or when it is called upon.

**Full Modal Script**

```
(function($){

    // Defining our jQuery plugin
    $.fn.modal_box = function(prop){

    // left: 37, up: 38, right: 39, down: 40,
    // spacebar: 32, pageup: 33, pagedown: 34, end: 35, home: 36
    var keys = [37, 38, 39, 40];

        function preventDefault(e) {
          e = e || window.event;
          if (e.preventDefault)
              e.preventDefault();
          e.returnValue = false;  
        }

        function keydown(e) {
            for (var i = keys.length; i--;) {
                if (e.keyCode === keys[i]) {
                    preventDefault(e);
                    return;
                }
            }
        }

        function wheel(e) {
          preventDefault(e);
        }

        function disable_scroll() {
          if (window.addEventListener) {
              window.addEventListener('DOMMouseScroll', wheel, false);
          }
          window.onmousewheel = document.onmousewheel = wheel;
          document.onkeydown = keydown;
        }

        function enable_scroll() {
            if (window.removeEventListener) {
                window.removeEventListener('DOMMouseScroll', wheel, false);
            }
            window.onmousewheel = document.onmousewheel = document.onkeydown = null;  
        }

        var options = $.extend({
            height : "500",
            width : "800",
        },prop);

        var from_top;
        var windowHeight = $(window).height();
        var windowWidth = $(window).width();

        return this.click(function(e){
            scrollbar = $(window).scrollTop();
            from_top = scrollbar + ((windowHeight / 2) -250);
            e.preventDefault();
            disable_scroll();
            add_block_page();
            add_popup_box();
            add_styles();
            $('.modal_box').fadeIn();
        });

         function add_styles(){         
            $('.modal_box').css({ 
                'position':'absolute', 
                'left':(windowWidth /2)-400 + 'px',
                'top': from_top,
                'display':'none',
                'margin':'10px',
                'border':'1px solid #fff',
                'box-shadow': '0px 2px 7px #292929',
                '-moz-box-shadow': '0px 2px 7px #292929',
                '-webkit-box-shadow': '0px 2px 7px #292929',
                'border-radius':'10px',
                '-moz-border-radius':'10px',
                '-webkit-border-radius':'10px',
                'background': '#f2f2f2', 
                'z-index':'50',
                'overflow':'hidden'
            });
            $('.modal_close').css({
                'position':'relative',
                'top':'-25px',
                'left':'20px',
                'float':'right',
                'display':'block',
                'height':'50px',
                'width':'50px',
                'background': 'url(images/close.png) no-repeat',
            });
            /*Block page overlay*/
            var pageHeight = $(document).height();
            var pageWidth = $(window).width();

            $('.block_page').css({
                'position':'absolute',
                'top':'0',
                'left':'0',
                'background-color':'rgba(0,0,0,0.6)',
                'height':pageHeight,
                'width':pageWidth,
                'z-index':'10'
            });
            $('.inner_modal_box').css({
                'background-color':'#fff',
                'height': options.height + 'px',
                'width': options.width + 'px',
                'padding':'10px',
                'margin':'15px',
                'border-radius':'10px',
                '-moz-border-radius':'10px',
                '-webkit-border-radius':'10px',
            });
        }

         function add_block_page(){
            var block_page = $('<div class="block_page"></div>');
            $(block_page).appendTo('body');
        }

         function add_popup_box(){
             var pop_up = $('<div class="modal_box"><a href="#" class="modal_close"></a><div class="inner_modal_box"><h2>' + options.title + '</h2><p>' + options.description + '</p></div></div>');
             $(pop_up).appendTo('.block_page');

             $('.modal_close').click(function(){
                event.preventDefault();
                $(this).parent().fadeOut().remove();
                $('.block_page').fadeOut().remove();                 
             });
        }

        return this;
    };

})(jQuery);
```

**JSFiddle** http://jsfiddle.net/3gu97cxn/

Comment: Do you have a jsfiddle for us to try or something? This is way too much code to ask us to dig through. And your PHP code should not matter. Please just show us the HTML (and preferably trim off the parts of your code that are not relevant to the question). That extremely long string of code in the **On click displays...** (whatever that means) bit is insane. Are we supposed to read through that? 'cause you haven't told us what it does. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: You cannot use PHP in JSFiddle

Comment: Let me make one and see if the same result happens

Comment: Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3gu97cxn/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The functions like

```
$('.TabSwitcher .Tab').click(function() {..
```

are not working for the modal because events can only be attached (at least, like this) to elements that are actually in the DOM when the page is loaded, and the `.Tabswitcher` is part of the modal that you are appending to the body later.
You can use `on()` to delegate the event from a parent element that is already in the DOM to the `.Tab` elements that are added later like this:

```
$(document).on("click", $('.TabSwitcher .Tab'), function(){...});
```

Instead of `$(document)` any parent element that is already in the DOM can be used to delegate the event.

For reference, you can check http://api.jquery.com/on/

Relevant part from there, section "Direct and delegated events":

> Event handlers are bound only to the currently selected elements; they must exist at the time your code makes the call to .on().